# How can a create a percentage matrix based on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like that :

```
data = {'Place A':['New York', 'Oslo', 'Oslo'], 'Place B':['Paris','London','London'], 'Type':['A','B','A'], 'Number' : [34,42,24]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

| Place A | Place B | Type | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York | Paris | A | 34 |
| Oslo | London | B | 42 |
| Oslo | London | A | 24 |

i need to have the percentage number of each type according to the routes.

I don't know witch command to use to get a dataframe that looks like this

| xxx | Paris | Oslo | London | New York |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paris | NaN | NaN | NaN | type A : 100% |
| Oslo | NaN | NaN | type A : 36,3% type B : 63,6% | NaN |
| London | NaN | type A : 36,3% type B : 63,6% | NaN | NaN |
| New York | type A : 100% | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IUUC, you could reshape the data, then compute the percent per group, finally reshape again:

```
cities = set([*df['Place A'], *df['Place B']])

df['total'] = df.groupby(['Place A', 'Place B'])['Number'].transform('sum')
df['percent'] = df['Number']/df['total']
df['value'] = df['Type']+': '+df['percent'].round(2).astype(str)

df2 = (df.groupby(['Place A', 'Place B'])['value']
         .agg(', '.join).unstack(1)
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
         .reindex(index=cities, columns=cities)
      )

# make output symmetrical
df2.update(df2.T)
```

output:

```
                      Oslo New York   Paris            London
Oslo                   NaN      NaN     NaN  B: 0.64, A: 0.36
New York               NaN      NaN  A: 1.0               NaN
Paris                  NaN   A: 1.0     NaN               NaN
London    B: 0.64, A: 0.36      NaN     NaN               NaN
```

If you don't need the symmetrical output, you can keep it by PlaceA/PlaceB, which will have the same information in condensed form:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Place A', 'Place B'])['value'].agg(', '.join).unstack(1)
```

output:

```
Place B             London   Paris
Place A                           
New York               NaN  A: 1.0
Oslo      B: 0.64, A: 0.36     NaN
```

Comment: On a big data frame I get a error that said : ValueError: unknown aggregate join

Comment: @Sarah double check your syntax, did you really use `.agg(', '.join)`?

Comment: Yes that is the right syntax that I used.., I will repost if I find how to fix this

Comment: Hard to know without a reproducible example for which it fails :/

Comment: It is the same as in the example, yet it has an index column (that is useless btw...)

Comment: I tested the example again and it works fine for me (pandas 1.4.1), please provide the full traceback

Comment: I guess it is because in my DF, some places are the same in column A and B..

Comment: Not sure this should matter, can you update the example?

Comment: Can I put a csv file ? It will be easier.. Maybe it's because places are not str and are numbers, New York = 18 for example

Comment: you can provide a link, yes

Comment: I just find out why it does not work, I was using Dask and not Pandas..